# How can holographic duals (eg. AdS/CFT) be used to study magnetic monopoles?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, ads-cft, magnetic-monopoles, holographic-principle, duality

What useful things are possible to find out about magnetic monopoles through the use of dual theories? I'm thinking of characteristics such as stability (or chaoticness), expectation values, central charge etc.

Also, how can duals be used to manipulate the system, and in what configurations would they serve as a useful tool? (eg. a black hole or a monopole wall)